# What is this construction "would have been ...to have done"?

Tags: grammar

> "It would have been hard for you to have said it more eloquently," said John.
>
> From White Horse Gery James.

Is it the same as "it would have been hard for you if you had tried to say it more eloquently?"

Comment: Please use specific question titles.

Comment: The basic gist of it is:  You said it nearly as eloquently as possible. It would be difficult to think of a way to say it that would be more eloquent than the way you put it.

Answer (score 1):

The construction of the quotation is a subject right extraposition.

The heavy subject is replaced by anticipatory *it* and echoed at the right end of the clause as the referent of *it*:

> [<sub>SUBJECT</sub>For you to have said it more eloquently]
>   [<sub>VERB</sub> would have been]
>   [<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub>hard]
>   ↓
>   [<sub>SUBJ</sub> It]
>   [<sub>VERB</sub> would have been]
>   [<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub>hard]
>   [<sub>REF</sub> for you to have said it more eloquently]

The subject is constructed as as a *for..to* subordinate clause: the verb in the base clause *You SAY it more eloquently* is recast as a marked infinitive and the clause is headed by the subordinator *for*.

Comment: If you had tried to say it more eloquently, it would have been hard for you. @user10395

Comment: I didn't. No sooner had you mentioned this than I noticed you had put it in your question. We just think alike! @user10395

Comment: @user10395 Not exactly. *You* is not the object of *for* here - it is not hard *for you*. *For* is a subordinator and its complement is *you HAVE said it more eloquently*.